# reagentc: Operation failed: 70

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have tried to apply [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/957256/156554), but failed at the last essential step. After executing `reagentc /enable` I was punched by Windows with error `Operation failed: 70`. What can be the cause?

I have tried [this very weird Russian idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TSs9AlIez8) of copying some dummy files to recovery drive, but that did not bring any solution in my case. I also tried (on contrary to above mentioned [solution](https://superuser.com/a/957256/156554)) to use [this guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dabbf334-8c74-4134-b3d7-e8572cd4cc03/reagentcexe-operation-failed-70?forum=mdopdart) and execute:

```
cmd /c copy %DEPLOYROOT%\DaRT\DaRT_10_x64.wim S:\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim
```

instead of:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Windows\System32\Recovery\ Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE\ /copyall /dcopy:t
```

Still no effect. I'm able to pass all the steps of both guides, but I'm unable to enable WinRE after copying it to recovery disk.

Is there any other source of `Operation failed: 70` error, that I should investigate?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro on board some cheap crappy tablet.

**Update** as requested in comments.

Dump of `reagentc /info` execution:

```
C:\Windows\system32>reagentc /info
Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE) and system reset configuration
Information:

    Windows RE status:         Disabled
    Windows RE location:
    Boot Configuration Data (BCD) identifier: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    Recovery image location:
    Recovery image index:      0
    Custom image location:
    Custom image index:        0

REAGENTC.EXE: Operation Successful.
```

Dump of `bcdedit /enum all` execution:

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {806b45c4-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
                        {806b45c0-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
                        {806b45c1-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
                        {806b45c2-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {806b45c8-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {806b45c0-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
description             EFI USB Device

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {806b45c1-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
description             EFI DVD/CDROM

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {806b45c2-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
description             EFI Network

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {806b45c4-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
description             Internal EFI Shell

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {806b45c6-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
device                  ramdisk=[unknown]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{806b45c7-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows Recovery Environment
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
displaymessage          Recovery
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
osdevice                ramdisk=[unknown]\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim,{806b45c7-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
systemroot              \windows
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
winpe                   Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {806b45c8-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Resume from Hibernate
---------------------
identifier              {806b45c8-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winresume.efi
description             Windows Resume Application
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {resumeloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
filedevice              partition=C:
filepath                \hiberfil.sys
bootmenupolicy          Standard
pae                     Yes
debugoptionenabled      No

Windows Memory Tester
---------------------
identifier              {memdiag}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\memtest.efi
description             Diagnostyka pamięci systemu Windows
locale                  en-GB
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes

EMS Settings
------------
identifier              {emssettings}
bootems                 No

Debugger Settings
-----------------
identifier              {dbgsettings}
debugtype               Serial
debugport               1
baudrate                115200

RAM Defects
-----------
identifier              {badmemory}

Global Settings
---------------
identifier              {globalsettings}
inherit                 {dbgsettings}
                        {emssettings}
                        {badmemory}

Boot Loader Settings
--------------------
identifier              {bootloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
                        {hypervisorsettings}

Hypervisor Settings
-------------------
identifier              {hypervisorsettings}
hypervisordebugtype     Serial
hypervisordebugport     1
hypervisorbaudrate      115200

Resume Loader Settings
----------------------
identifier              {resumeloadersettings}
inherit                 {globalsettings}
```

Dump of `DISKPART> sel dis 0` execution:

```
Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    System             100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Reserved           128 MB   101 MB
  Partition 3    Primary             14 GB   229 MB
  Partition 4    Recovery           300 MB    14 GB
```

Dump of `dir /s /b /a Q:\` execution:

```
Q:\Recovery
Q:\System Volume Information
Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE
Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE\ReAgent.xml
Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim
```

Comment: Look, it's a little bit tricky. Please run these commands and update your post with provided output. `reagentc /info` and `bcdedit /enum all` and `dir /s /b /a X:\ ` where X is your recovery drive. Please also run `diskpart` and run `sel dis 0` and then `list part` and send me the output.

Comment: @AmirHossein Dumps provided, as requested.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you respect the time I spent to help you, try it one last time. Credit is not everything, I answered to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You neither have *boot.sdi* file in your *WinRE* folder, nor as a *Boot Configuration* entry. First of all, you have to delete the current *BCD* entry for *Windows Recovery Environment*. Open an elevated `cmd` and run this:

```
bcdedit /delete {806b45c6-eb06-11e4-a57c-ba3c4dbbc856} /cleanup
```

Now, try to copy *boot.sdi* to your *WinRE* folder (it's available in your *System32* folder):

```
xcopy boot.sdi Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE /h /v
```

Now, set the location of your WinRE image, and point it to recover your current OS:

```
reagentc /setreimage /path Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target %windir%
```

Now, if faced no error, you're all set to enable it:

```
reagentc /enable
```

Make sure everything is fine:

```
reagentc /info
```

Now, to check it's working, run this and then restart. It will bring up WindowsRE automatically upon next reboot:

```
reagentc /boottore
```

If you're all set, remove the Recovery partition Letter by running:

```
Diskpart
remove letter=Q
```

Report the results. Good Luck!

**Update:**

`Operation failed: 70` seems to occur due to recovery partition volume overflow. 300MB was enough for Windows 7, but you need at least 450MB for Recovery Partition in Windows 10. You have to shrink at least 150MB from your Windows Partition and expand your recovery partition. To do so:

First of all, save your *Winre.wim*:

```
xcopy Q:\Recovery\WindowsRE\Winre.wim Recovery /h /v
```

Now to fix partition size:

```
diskpart
remove letter=Q
sel dis 0
sel part 4
del part override
sel part 3
shrink desired=150
create part primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Recovery"
set id="de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac"
assign letter=R
```

Create folder structure:

```
mkdir R:\Recovery\WindowsRE
```

And bring the files back:

```
xcopy Recovery\Winre.wim R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /h /v
xcopy boot.sdi R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /h /v
```

Now configure and enable it:

```
reagentc /setreimage /path R:\Recovery\WindowsRE /target %windir%
reagentc /enable
```

To check it works upon next reboot:

```
reagentc /boottore
```

Comment: Your solution didn't help me. After `reagentc /enable` I'm getting the same `Operation failed: 70` error. However, I must tell you, that I'm tired with this stuff and I'm generally tired with Windows 10, so I'm accepting your answers as a thank for your effect, but I'm not going to go further this way and I'm going to install Windows 7 on that device.

Comment: Look, it has nothing to do with windows 10! It's WinRE problem. I Experienced it before. Are you sure you wanna give up?

Comment: I think, it _has_ anything to do with Windows 10 after all! :) It's Windows 10's Bitlocker that has smashed my WinRE and caused me all these problems, it wasn't me or any other program. But yes, you're right. To respect your time spent on solving my problem, I'm going to give it another try. Just give me some hours to test this one. BTW: Wouldn't it be easier to expand recovery partition using _Disk Management_ tool instead of playing with console and diskpart (prone to many errors)?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you can shrink and expand using Disk Management Tool, but you **CAN'T** set Recovery Partition ID, neither assign letter to a protected partition. That's why I wrote it all in `diskpart` because 1 way or another, you have to use it at some point :) BTW, what you mean about Bitlocker? You've set Bitlocker on recovery partition???

Comment: Clarification about the Russian guy's video: He wasn't trying to fix the problem by duplication of a weird file inside recovery partition. The first message he was getting upon `reagentc /enable` is a `Operation Successful` messge. Then he duplicates a 3MB file there, until it ran out of necessary free space (I guess it needs some free space to expand something on boot up) and after the last `/enable` command, he gets an `Operation failed: 70` but in Russian :) The fact is when I checked on my notebook, I figured out Windows 10 *Winre.wim* is 300MB itself! How you put it there?Is DaRT lighter?

Comment: I need more time to test your solution, but I'll certainly test it and report the results. No, of course not. I tried to enable Bitlocker on system drive (c:). In first step it removed WinRE from recovery partition (reasons unknown) and in the last step it wasn't able to save recovery key to any source (neither disk nor account -- reasons again unknown) and thus entire operation was cancelled. But due to stupid bugs in Bitlocker WinRE was not rolled back and my WinRE environment remains unset ever since then.

Comment: Here's the proof: *"If the partition is less than 500 MB, it must have at least 50 MB of free space."* Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824839.aspx

Comment: Up-to-date requirements – https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions